# UNetBootin Unable to Detect Encrypted USB Drive?

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount, encryption

I'm using UnetBootin to create startup disks, but it can't seem to detect my encrypted USB flash drive I creased using the Disks utility. The encrypted layer is unlocked, and the primary layer is mounted. Is there any way to resolve this?

**EDIT 0:**

`Startup Disk Creator` could see it just fine, seems to be a programming/configuration error.

[image: Disks]

[image: UNetBootin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Unetbootin

Unetbootin wants a partition with the FAT32 file system on the target pendrive. I think it needs a plain file system without encryption, so you must prepare the pendrive (overwrite the current partition) before starting Unetbootin.

You can use for example Disks (`gnome-disks`) or `gparted` or `mkusb` to create a partition with the FAT32 file system.

### Alternative

If you use a *cloning tool*, for example the new Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator (in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions), Disks (`gnome-disks`) or `mkusb`, the cloning process will work directly. It will overwrite what was there before as long as the pendrive is healthy and can be written to.

### Tools

`gparted` is available in the live sessions of Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours, but you must install it in installed systems,

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

`mkusb`is available via a Launchpad PPA according to the following link

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)